# (python) Найти наибольшую группу соприкасающихся друг с другом элементов двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы

У меня имеется код, вычисляющий наибольшее количество соприкасающихся одинаковых элементов двумерного массива (Но только, если задать этот элемент внутри функции (у меня это (def count_region_cells(matrix, row, col))

Это весь код:

```
def checkio(matrix):
    def maxRegion(matrix):
        max_cell_counter = 0
        for row in range(len(matrix)):
            for col in range(len(matrix[0])):
                region_cell_count = count_region_cells(matrix, row, col)
                max_cell_counter = max(max_cell_counter, region_cell_count)
        return max_cell_counter
        

    def count_region_cells(matrix, row, col):
            
        if any([row<0, col<0, row >= len(matrix), col >= len(matrix[0])]):
            return 0
        
        if matrix[row][col] != 1:
            return 0
        
        cell_count = 1
        matrix[row][col] = 0
        
        for r in range(row - 1, row + 2):
            for c in range(col - 1, col + 2):
                if any([r == row, c == col]):
                    cell_count += count_region_cells(matrix, r, c)
            
        return cell_count
    return maxRegion(matrix)
```

Внутри этой функции есть строчка, обозначающая, какой элемент мне нужно рассматривать (в моём случае это 1 (т.е. если в ближайших клетках по вертикали и горизонтали больше нету единичек, то функция завершает свою работу)) (ДИАГОНАЛИ НЕ УЧИТЫВАЕМ):

Отрывок функции, которая ищет соседей (но только соседей единички):

```
def count_region_cells(matrix, row, col):
            
        if any([row<0, col<0, row >= len(matrix), col >= len(matrix[0])]):
            return 0
        
        if matrix[row][col] != 1:
            return 0
```

У меня то ли мозг перегрелся, то ли что, но я никак не могу сделать так, чтобы функция учитывала ВСЕ элементы массива, а не только заданный внутри функции и возвращала максимальное количество соприкасающихся одинаковых элементов. Как подобное можно провернуть?

Пример матрицы:

```
[[1,1,5,1,1,4,2],
 [2,4,3,2,3,4,5],
 [1,5,4,4,4,1,1],
 [1,4,4,2,5,1,3],
 [4,4,1,1,1,5,3],
 [4,2,1,3,5,3,3],
 [4,5,2,1,4,5,5]]
```

Правильным ответом для неё является [4, 9] (четвёрка соседствует с другими четвёрками 9 раз; остальные элементы соседствуют меньше 9 раз)

Воть так воть (заменил остальные элементы на нолик для наглядности):

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,4,4,4,0,0],
 [0,4,4,0,0,0,0],
 [4,4,0,0,0,0,0],
 [4,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [4,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: у вас все эти четверки соседствуют. Только такие интересуют, или разрывы тоже допустимы?

Comment: только соседствующие. Если где-то в далеке (например, вся первая строка) тоже есть цепочка из четвёрок, то эти 2 цепочки надо сравнить и вывести наибольшую